# Android: POPULATE 4 SPINNERS BASED ON SELECTION OF 1,2 & 3 SPINNERS

Tags: android, spinner

am very new to android development and i am trying to make a mutli spinners that relay on each other, i have successfully made one relay on another, but i cant make 3rd to relay on the 2nd, nor 4th to relay on the 3rd.

Appreciate your help

Here is my XML

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:entries="@array/Type" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
```

and here is my java

```
public class VehicleProfile extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner s1,s2, s3, s4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_profile);
    s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    s4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.contentEquals("List-1")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Model");
        list.add("Alfa Romeo");
        list.add("Audi");
        list.add("BMW");
        list.add("Chevrolet");
        list.add("Citroen");
        list.add("Dacia");
        list.add("Ford");
        list.add("Honda");
        list.add("hyundai");
        list.add("Jaguar");
        list.add("KIA");
        list.add("KTM");
        list.add("Land Rover");
        list.add("Mazda");
        list.add("Mercedes-Benz");
        list.add("Mini Cooper");
        list.add("Nissan");
        list.add("Opel");
        list.add("Peugeot");
        list.add("Porsche");
        list.add("Renault");
        list.add("Saab");
        list.add("SEAT");
        list.add("Skoda");
        list.add("Volvo");
        list.add("VW");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("List-2")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Model");
        list.add("Alfa Romeo");
        list.add("Audi");
        list.add("BMW");
        list.add("Cadillac");
        list.add("Chevrolet");
        list.add("Chrysler");
        list.add("Citroen");
        list.add("Dacia");
        list.add("Daewoo");
        list.add("Dodge");
        list.add("Fiat");
        list.add("Ford");
        list.add("Honda");
        list.add("Hymer");
        list.add("hyundai");
        list.add("Infiniti");
        list.add("Isuzu");
        list.add("Iveco");
        list.add("Jaguar");
        list.add("Jeep");
        list.add("KIA");
        list.add("Lancia");
        list.add("Land Rover");
        list.add("Lexus");
        list.add("Maserati");
        list.add("Mazda");
        list.add("Mercedes-Benz");
        list.add("MG");
        list.add("MG(Rover)");
        list.add("Mini Cooper");
        list.add("Mitsubishi");
        list.add("Nissan");
        list.add("Opel");
        list.add("Peugeot");
        list.add("Porsche");
        list.add("Renault");
        list.add("Rover");
        list.add("Saab");
        list.add("SEAT");
        list.add("Skoda");
        list.add("Smart");
        list.add("SsangYong");
        list.add("Subaru");
        list.add("Suzuki");
        list.add("Toyota");
        list.add("Volvo");
        list.add("VW");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }


}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I have tried to put this 2 function before [public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {], , but it did not work, i can see the spiners in the page, but they are empty and cant be opened

```
String sp2= String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp2.contentEquals("Alfa Romeo")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Engine");
        list.add("145 1.9 JTD 8V");
        list.add("146 1.9 JTD 8V");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
    }

    String sp3= String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp3.contentEquals("145 1.9 JTD 8V")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Engine");
        list.add("77 kw, 105 hp, 255 nm");
        list.add("146 1.9 JTD 8V");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The spinner two and three do not fire onItemSelected you should add :

```
    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

edit your code like this :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (arg1.getId()==R.id.spnnier1){
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.contentEquals("List-1")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Model");
        list.add("Alfa Romeo");
        list.add("Audi");
        list.add("BMW");
        list.add("Chevrolet");
        list.add("Citroen");
        list.add("Dacia");
        list.add("Ford");
        list.add("Honda");
        list.add("hyundai");
        list.add("Jaguar");
        list.add("KIA");
        list.add("KTM");
        list.add("Land Rover");
        list.add("Mazda");
        list.add("Mercedes-Benz");
        list.add("Mini Cooper");
        list.add("Nissan");
        list.add("Opel");
        list.add("Peugeot");
        list.add("Porsche");
        list.add("Renault");
        list.add("Saab");
        list.add("SEAT");
        list.add("Skoda");
        list.add("Volvo");
        list.add("VW");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    if(sp1.contentEquals("List-2")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Model");
        list.add("Alfa Romeo");
        list.add("Audi");
        list.add("BMW");
        list.add("Cadillac");
        list.add("Chevrolet");
        list.add("Chrysler");
        list.add("Citroen");
        list.add("Dacia");
        list.add("Daewoo");
        list.add("Dodge");
        list.add("Fiat");
        list.add("Ford");
        list.add("Honda");
        list.add("Hymer");
        list.add("hyundai");
        list.add("Infiniti");
        list.add("Isuzu");
        list.add("Iveco");
        list.add("Jaguar");
        list.add("Jeep");
        list.add("KIA");
        list.add("Lancia");
        list.add("Land Rover");
        list.add("Lexus");
        list.add("Maserati");
        list.add("Mazda");
        list.add("Mercedes-Benz");
        list.add("MG");
        list.add("MG(Rover)");
        list.add("Mini Cooper");
        list.add("Mitsubishi");
        list.add("Nissan");
        list.add("Opel");
        list.add("Peugeot");
        list.add("Porsche");
        list.add("Renault");
        list.add("Rover");
        list.add("Saab");
        list.add("SEAT");
        list.add("Skoda");
        list.add("Smart");
        list.add("SsangYong");
        list.add("Subaru");
        list.add("Suzuki");
        list.add("Toyota");
        list.add("Volvo");
        list.add("VW");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

  }
else 



if (arg1.getId()==R.id.spinner2){
     String sp2= String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp2.contentEquals("Alfa Romeo")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Engine");
        list.add("145 1.9 JTD 8V");
        list.add("146 1.9 JTD 8V");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
    }
   else 
       if (arg1.getId()==R.id.spinner3){
    String sp3= String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp3.contentEquals("145 1.9 JTD 8V")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Select Engine");
        list.add("77 kw, 105 hp, 255 nm");
        list.add("146 1.9 JTD 8V");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
    }
```

}

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_profile);
        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        s4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: I add it like this , but it wont even allow me to make a selection from the 2nd spinner

Comment: the arg1.getId allows you to captuer the changed spinner

Comment: I have edit it again there was some errors in the past one please repute up if it works

Comment: I took your code copy/past and add the missing brackets at the end, but now i can only see the values inside the first spinner

Comment: once you chose list1 or list2 the values of the second spinner should be avaliable